# Update a buggy installation

Tags: php, updates, phpmyadmin, backup

My site is pretty slow , so I am looking to update the wordpress in hopes of getting it back on track.
What are best practices?

because ,

getting few PHP notice & warnings in the Debug log. + The HTML takes too long too load.

mysqld.bin takes 97-99 % cpu ... any help would highly appreciated.

Let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: The "best practice", is the usual: make a backup, then upgrade and test everything. Not sure why you think this case is special?

Comment: Apparently the site is working fine , but suddenly server is not responding & giving request_timed_out error. So just to see if it is WP related , I am doing it. I don't want to mess anything in perfectly working website. & yes , doing this for the first time. that's y.

Answer (score 2):

You have **two** tasks to solve here: 1. Resolve the time-out problem. 2. Update WordPress.

#### Resolve the time-out problem

These things don't just happen because your WP is old. There must be a concrete reason.

The three most common reasons are:

1. Not enough memory. Maybe your hosting provider has limited the memory?
   Try adding the following line in your `wp-config.php` above the "Happy blogging" line:

   ```
    define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
   ```

   If that doesn't help, ask your provider.
2. A very large option is stored in your database and fetched on every request. Go to your database management tool, like phpMyAdmin, and sort the `wp_options` table (assuming your table prefix is `wp_` by the size of the `value` column. If there is any very large option, consider deleting it. But make a database backup first!
3. Some plugin is making a request to an external source, overriding WordPress’ pre-set time-out, and the remote site doesn't respond in time. Disable all plugins, and see if that helps. Then re-enable them one after another, until the issue reappears. Deactivate that plugin, and try to find an alternative.

#### Update WordPress

1. Make a backup of your database.
2. Make a backup of your uploads. They shouldn't be affected by the update, but it's always nice to have that backup.
3. If you are using a default theme (named Twenty-X) and made changes to it — which you [absolutely shouldn't](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) — back up that theme too.
4. Disable all plugins, and switch to a default theme.
5. Update WordPress.
6. Re-enable the theme and the plugins, again one by one, check that everything is working as expected. If it doesn't, you might need your backups to roll everything back, but that's not very likely.
7. Update your plugins.

That's it.

There are tools like [Deployer](https://deployer.org) that can help automate this process, and they make it easy to roll back a broken update within seconds to the last working state. You might want to learn using such a tool.

Comment: Tried the first one & no help. Will try to figure out rest of the options.

Comment: Thanks, fuxia. wp_options is showing size=547.5Mib & Total size of all tables is =630.9 Mib ..... is that normal ?

Comment: @DhavalJoshi No, that's quite a lot. Try to find the largest values.

Comment: I tried the wp optimize plugin & used to delete the transients.There are 839 post revisions. is it safe to delete?

Comment: @DhavalJoshi If you are sure you don't need the revisions, you can delete them. But they are not part of your current problem. Solve the actual issues first. :)

Comment: yes the size still stands at 628.53 MB. what shall we do ? Does turning on log add to wp_options table?

Comment: @DhavalJoshi What's the name and size of the three largest entries?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, it took me time to come up with the query.
These r top 10 entries

| rs-templates                                     |
| _transient_feed_cd43c96e0a956d0642f6b5bb05816ca1 |
| _transient_feed_40a89299829082877949471eeb1c21e3 |
| wphb-last-report                                 |
| wphb_scripts_collection                          |
| _dike_live_search_products                       |
| rs-library                                       |
| _site_transient_update_plugins                   |
| w3tc_minify                                      |
| fs_accounts

Comment: This is the query I ran =select option_name from wp_options order by char_length(option_value) desc limit 10;

Comment: | option_name                                      | char_length(option_value) |
+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| rs-templates                                     |                    722430 |
| _transient_feed_cd43c96e0a956d0642f6b5bb05816ca1 |                    192536 |
| _transient_feed_40a89299829082877949471eeb1c21e3 |                    164382 |
| wphb-last-report                                 |                    156892 |
| wphb_scripts_collection                          |                    136454 |

Comment: So `rs-templates` comes probably from your theme. Looks like it comes with some kind of "template builder". But that's just 705 kb, right? That can't be the problem. Maybe there are many redundant options later on? It's hard to say without looking at it directly.

Comment: that's not possible now. the server isn't responding. can't even ssh.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Without your insights this might not have been possible. Hats-off. Let me tell you what happened , the server went down , nothing was accessible , not even SSH. If i wouldn't have known about the wp_options table bloating. The game was over. @fuxia

Comment: there , help needed?